# bootstrap column auto center column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap col, like below:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
```

Now as we have just 3 div so it will not cover whole column is there any way that these two will show in center instead from left to right?

Please tell way to do same

**Also issue is col are generated dynamically:**

so if u have 5 blocks then 12/5= 2 so

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 half-padding">hi</div>
```

Comment: Totally how many divs you have?

Comment: these div are generated dynamically

Comment: Why do you have "" after half-padding?

Comment: @mourjewels Did you check my answer?

Comment: i updated my qusn i can not change col-2 to col-3 as there are generated by code to distribute blocks in proper way inside row value

Comment: whatever you have. you should wrap them and center as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a offset classes in bootstrap to shift div's use below html to get what you want exactly

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2 half-padding">hi</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2 half-padding">hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `4-columns 8-columns` div layout make `6-columns 12-columns` div and wrap them in a div and center it:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 half-padding">hi</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 half-padding">hi</div>
</div>

.wrap {
    max-width: 700px;    /* define as your layout */
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```